# Get VSCode to recognize variable is being used in different javascript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

I have an electron project that is split into multiple windows, with several javascript files for each window. My problem is that there is no recognition that these files are linked by VS Code. For Example:
A variable declared in "mainwindow/constants.js" and then used in "mainwindow/socketFunction.js", will show up as greyed out and `is declared but the value is never read`. Likewise, if a function is declared in a certain file and used in another, ctrl-clicking the function name to go to function declaration does not work.

Is there any way to get VS code to recognize the structure of the files, ie: that variables declared in one file are the same that are being used in another.

EDIT: my file structure looks like this if it helps

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some more information. which module system are you using in your project? Are you using ES6 import statement or AMD module system or CJS ?

Comment: I'm using NPM and require. I think this has more to do with VSCode configuration than the project itself tho. IE. I could just be writing completely vanilla javascript with no packages or anything and get the sam behavior

Comment: Actually none of the javascript text editor works that way, some thirdparty plugin works in a unreliable fashion. Since javascript is a dynamic typed language and if you dont  use module system, editor can't find those packages.

Comment: It is simple. Just select the variable and click the right button on mouse & then click on `Go to References`.